# Where can I view Web Deployment history?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm managing a third party vendor that uses Microsoft Web Deploy to push an ASP.NET website to our server.  Is there somewhere I can find a history of where/when the files were published?

According to [the MS Docs](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy), Web Deploy automatically logs to the event log at Applications > Microsoft Web Deploy, but when I look there I don't see anything related to Web Deploy.

PS - I know that I can look at the timestamp on the app's folder in our filesystem, but that only gives me the time of the very last change, and not who made it...

**Update** - Under Event Viewer > Application and Service Logs > Microsoft > Microsoft Web Deploy, I can see history of web deployments that encountered an error, but I do not see a history of successful deployments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this is old, but I found this while looking for the solution myself and stumbled upon the full log.

Instead of directly going to the Web Deploy folder in the event view, navigate to Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> WebDeploy.  From there you can view ConnectionInfo to review successful deployments

Comment: Old or not it's still relevant! If I might add, by default the Info level is disabled. To enable it, simple open the properties of the Info log under the folder you mentioned, and check Enable logging. The next time a deployment is done, you'll see everything in there. By default, only the Error and ConnectionInfo logs are enabled, and the ConnectionInfo log doesn't show who did what so it's not very useful.

Comment: And in case it's not totally obvious, you're looking in the Event Viewer on the _target_ server, not the machine from which you're deploying...

Answer (score 2):

I found this in  %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\logs\WMSvc.  Timestamp, AD username, and sitename published.  All I needed!