# How to determine when web application was last published?

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

Without logging into the destination web server and checking the Date Modified on the project's DLL file, how would I determine the date / time I last published a web application project from Visual Studio 2015?

- Using the built-in Publish Web feature
- Using Web Deploy as the Publish Method

[image: Publish Method selector]

#### Edit:

`{project}.dll` gets a new Date Modified in the `bin` folder, and even in the `obj\{PublishProfileName}` folder on a Rebuild. I was really hoping the latter would answer my question about when we last published from the machine runnning VS.

I was trying to determine what happened after the fact. Something similar to the question here [Where can I view Web Deployment history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616233/where-can-i-view-web-deployment-history). I also only see Errors, not Connection Info. Wondering if there's somewhere else to look in my scenario.

Comment: The question assumes you are publishing using visual studio and not just copying files.

Answer (score 4):

You could publish the DLL's version:  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` and build date in the source of the page. You can find the version number in the assembly info, and the build date and time can be determined using the method shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600990/390421

Comment: Useful option if you're planning ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Only for build time, not publish time.